# Enable GPU for Python programming with VS Code on Windows 10 (llama-cpp-python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, gpu, large-language-model, llama-cpp-python

I struggled alot while enabling GPU on my 32GB Windows 10 machine with 4GB Nvidia P100 GPU during Python programming. My LLMs did not use the GPU of my machine while inferencing. After spending few days on this I thought I will summarize my step by step approach which worked for me

1. Install C++ distribution. I did it via Visual Studio 2022 Installer and installing packages under "Desktop Development with C++" and checking the option "Windows 10 SDK (10.0.20348.0) as shown in this image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLDy7.png). Install the packages.
2. Download and Install Nvidia CUDA Toolkit (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)
3. Ensure that CUDA_PATH variable is set in your environment variables
4. In Visual Studio Code, set the following environment variables:

```bash
$env:CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_CUBLAS=on"
$env:CUDACXX="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.2\bin\nvcc.exe"
```

5. Finally run:

```py
pip install llama-cpp-python --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

Then, when running the python program, you will see that BLAS is set to 1
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKIkV.png)

Hope it helps the community too!!!

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer and accept it by clicking on tick icon ✅ which is at left of the answer, so that community can understand that the question has been answered.  See [can I answer my own question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a blog, it's a Q & A site. However, you may answer your own question, but the first step is asking a question, and this is what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install C++ distribution. I did it via Visual Studio 2022 Installer
   and installing packages under "Desktop Development with C++" and
   checking the option "Windows 10 SDK (10.0.20348.0) as shown in this
   image
2. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLDy7.png). Install the packages.
   Download and Install Nvidia CUDA Toolkit
   (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)
3. Ensure that CUDA_PATH variable is set in your environment variables
4. In Visual Studio Code, set the following environment variables
   $env:CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_CUBLAS=on" $env:CUDACXX="C:\Program
   Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.2\bin\nvcc.exe"
5. Finally run pip install llama-cpp-python --no-cache-dir
   --force-reinstall --upgrade